Implicit vs Explicit Euler method
I have the following diffusion partial differential equation
$$
\frac{\partial{s}}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^{2}s}{\partial x^{2}} + \sigma \frac{s}{1+s} = 0, \quad \forall t \in [0,T], \forall x \in [0,1]
$$
where $s(x,t)$ is the function measuring the concentration at time $t$ and point $x$ with boundary conditions $s(t,0) = \alpha, s(t,1) = \beta$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ and $s(0,x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.
Now, using a centered finite difference scheme, we can turn this into
$$ 
S^{(k+1)} = S^{(k)} - \tau \left([A(S^{(k)}]S^{(k+1)} -b \right)
$$
using implicit Euler for the integration step where $S^{(k)}$ is the vector of concentrations at step $k$, $A(S)$ is the tridiagonal metrix from the scheme and $b$ the initial conditions.
In this case, I know that in order to solve it, I need to solve a system of linear equations of the form
$$
[I + \tau A(S^{(k+1)})]S^{(k+1)} = S^{k} + \tau b
$$
In Octave, I did this via
    LHS = eye(N-1) + tau * A;
    RHS = S + tau * b;

    % Solve the linear system
    S_new = LHS \ RHS;

    S = S_new;

Now I'd like to use explicit Euler to compare the results but changing the code to
   S_new = S - tau * (A * S - b);
   % Update S for the next step
   S = S_new;

leads to some odd results. Am I misunderstanding the switch to explicit Euler or missing a few steps here?
EDIT
The finite difference scheme rewrites it as
$$
s'_{j}(t) + \frac{-s_{j+1}(t) + 2s_{j}(t) - s_{j-1}(t)}{h^{2}} + \sigma \frac{s_{j}(t)}{1+s_{j}(t)} = 0
$$
with $s_{0}(t) = \alpha, s_{N}(t) = \beta$ and $s_{j}(0) = 0$.
This can be written in the matrix form
$$
S'(t) = f(t, S(t)), \quad S(0) = 0
$$
where $f(t, S(t)) = -([A(S)]S - b)$ with $A(S)$ having
$$
a_{jj} = \frac{2}{h^{2}} + \frac{\sigma}{1+s_{j}(t)}, \quad a_{j, j+1} = a_{j+1, j} = \frac{-1}{h^{2}}
$$
and $b = (\alpha/h^{2}, 0, \ldots, 0, \beta/h^{2})$ as our vector of initial conditions.
SECOND EDIT
We can see that the Implicit method gives the nice solution we ought to expect in this case.

The explicit one basically explodes, for a lack of better term.

Is the problem with using Explicit Euler the fact that in this case, $\frac{\tau}{h^{2}} > \frac{1}{2}$ and the scheme is thus unstable?

Can you explain how you arrived at your equation for $S^{(k+1)}$?  Where has $\sigma$ gone and how did $b$ end up here?

We initially rewrite the equation in a matrix form $S'(t) = f(t,S(t))$ with $f(t,S(t)) = -([A(S)]S-b)$, where $A(S)$ is the tridiagonal matrix with $2/h^{2} + \sigma/(1+s_{j}(t))$ on the main diagonal and $-1/h^{2}$ on the first upper and lower diagonals. The vector $b$ is the vector of initial conditions $b = (\alpha/h{2}, \ldots, \beta/h^{2})$ with $h = 1/N$ our step size.

Oke, could you then add the definition of $A$ to your question? But I still do not understand why the $b$ shows up, your discretization becomes $S^{(k+1)}=S^{(k)}+\tau A(S^{(k)})S^{(k)}$

However, I do understand your problem now: because $A$ is a function of $S$, the linear equation you solve is not linear.

The solution of the heat equation and similar ones is extremely unstable for explicit methods as the second derivative or Laplacian can have some very large negative eigenvalues. This gives frequency components along the space axis that get amplified in each step as you observed. The obvious solution is, as also observed, to use implicit methods. (Or operator splitting etc. which removes these frequencies from the numerical method and treats them more-or-less exactly.)

See also stable MATLAB implementation using Method of lines MSE_Q5010873

@LutzLehmann Right, that would explain the second plot I added to the question description. I was asking because the professor made it sound like we should get a similar, although more error-prone, result in the end and it got me confused. Well, technically he wanted us to plot solutions for time steps of 0.02 and 0.0002 and see what we get.

@gpmath Also thank you for the provided file, quite useful

@ThomasPetit In your implicit solution all curves should start and end in the same points
to meet the boundary conditions $s(t,0) = \alpha, s(t,1) = \beta$.

@gpmath For this particular problem we have $\alpha = 0.2, \beta = 1, \sigma = 10, \tau = 0.02, N = 30$, where $\tau$ is the time step and $N$ the spatial division size. Admittedly, the graph is cut off a little to the sides but hopefully the solutions should match, if I haven't gotten anything mixed up.

@ThomasPetit Reducing the step size should reduce the error according to the order of the method. But (for stiff problems) there is an upper step size to this effect, and on the other end if the number of steps gets too large you get a corresponding accumulation of floating point errors. So for non-toy problems the selection of method and step size is critical.

Sorry, but OP's graph "Implicit Euler Solution" isn't correct.
See the correct solution: MSE_Q5010873
